# How to merge two SQL scripts?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My task is to automate some actions (deleting old rows from a DB), which now are done manually.
Currently I have two MSSQL scripts.
The first one fetches IDs, I have to work with, as well as a number of rows to delete for every ID. And it looks like that:

```
SELECT e.batchId, b.Name, count (*) "Count"
FROM dbo.[Logs] e
join [dbo.[Batch] b on b.Id = e.batchId
Group by e.batchId, b.Name
Having count(*) > 500
order by [Count]
```

So, after i recieve all the IDs I have to work with, I launch the second one script for every ID (changing its number in a script manually and relunching it for every row from the first one select):

```
Declare @counter INT
Declare @fdel INT
Declare @csize INT
Declare @batchId INT

select @batchId=666777 --HERE IS AN ID I CHANGE MANUALLY AND RELAUNCH THE SECOND ONE SCRIPT FOR IT
select @csize=500
select @counter = 0
select @fdel=count(*) from dbo.Logs where batchId = @batchId

While (@counter < @fdel)
BEGIN
select @counter = @counter + @csize
BEGIN TRAN
DELETE top(@csize) from dbo.Logs where batchId = @batchId
COMMIT TRAN
END
```

So, how can those scripts be combined in one, to launch the whole script only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost completed [CURSOR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx) declaration. Without discussion of the solution itself, your code with "merged" queries would look like:

```
/* your declared variables and cursor variable */
DECLARE
    @crBatches CURSOR,
    @counter INT,
    @fdel INT,
    @csize INT = 500,
    @batchId INT

/* your first query declared as cursor/source for looping through batch_ids */
SET @crBatches = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT e.batchId, count (*) "Count"
FROM dbo.[Logs] e
join [dbo.[Batch] b on b.Id = e.batchId
Group by e.batchId, b.Name
Having count(*) > 500
order by [Count]

OPEN @crBatches

FETCH NEXT FROM @crBatches
INTO @batchId, @fdel

/* loop on batch_ids obtained from cursor */
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @counter = 0

    /* internal loop - your second query */
    While (@counter < @fdel)
    BEGIN
        SET @counter = @counter + @csize

        BEGIN TRAN
        DELETE top(@csize) from dbo.Logs where batchId = @batchId
        COMMIT TRAN
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM @crBatches
    INTO @batchId, @fdel
END

CLOSE @crBatches
DEALLOCATE @crBatches
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subselect and where in

```
delete from dbo.Logs
where id in (  select id_to_del from 
    ( SELECT e.batchId as id_to_del, b.Name, count (*) "Count"
      FROM dbo.[Logs] e
      join [dbo.[Batch] b on b.Id = e.batchId
      Group by e.batchId, b.Name
      Having count(*) > 500
      order by [Count]) );
```